# Skip CSS block for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am designing a responsive website. My CSS file starts with a block for the mobile layout, followed by a media query for the notepad layout and another media query for the desktop layout. I would like to make some concessions for IE8, which does not support media queries. SO, as currently structured, when my site is viewed in IE8, it reverts to the mobile layout, which is the first CSS block encountered in the style sheet. Not a good look for a desktop monitor, which I would expect the IE8 user to be.

1. Is it possible to insert some code in the CSS sheet that says "If you are an old IE browser, go to the desktop block for the layout?" OR, "Skip the mobile layouts"? ALternatively, I can create a separate IE CSS sheet, using conditional comments in the source code to call it up. If that's the way to go.
2. Will the extra style sheet be a drag on the load time for my page? (There's a limit to how far I'll go to accommodate people still on IE8!)

Comment: For point 1. Have a look at [browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I like the way html5 boilerplate handles conditionals.  It attaches ie classes to the html tag like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
```

It makes it pretty easy to target what you want after that. [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) talks about it. I would probably just stick with one large css file rather than have multiple, unless it's only one page of my site or I want to punish ie users.

Comment: I have something like that in my page:
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->

But I'm not sure what to do with it. My website comprises about 16 different pages, each with three layouts in the .css file (for three screen sizes) separated by 2 media queries. The default is the mobile layout, so it's the first one on the page and the only one read by IE8; I want IE8 to skip that and go to the desktop layout, which follows this media query: @media only screen and (min-width: 769px)

So... I guess I have a class defined as "ie8 oldie." How do I use that to make this happen?

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?  I would love to take a look at the css to get a better idea of how to answer your question.  From my experience, ie8 does not recognize media queries so it seems like it should ignore all of your media queries and only render the non-media query rules.

Comment: This seems to have some relevant tips: [smashingmagazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/)

Comment: The site isn't up yet. Although I'm not targeting IE8 users per se, I want then to at least see a desktop layout. Instead, they will see the single column layout because I'm using a mobile first design-- THat article you sent me describes this exact problem: "The elephant in the room is Internet Explorer for the desktop. With a mobile-first solution, large screens will display the content in one column…" I didn't completely follow their solution, but it looks like the way to go is a conditional style sheet. Seems to work. (Not sure how to use the classes in the boilerplate you posted.) Thanks!